Invariance property of MLE - Proof
I am reading a proof about the invariance property of the MLE but there is a equality that does not make sense to me. Suppose $\tau(\cdot)$ is a one to one function, define $\eta = \tau(\theta)$ so we have $\theta = \tau^{-1}(\eta)$. In Casella and Berger, there is the equality
$$\mathcal{L}^*(\eta|\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\tau^{-1}(\eta))$$
but shouldn't it be
$$\mathcal{L}^*(\eta|\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\tau(\eta))$$
instead?
Any tip is useful!

Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596186/how-to-prove-mathcali-1-eta-mathcali-1-thetah-eta2-whe/596204#596204

If $\tau$ is invertible, it shouldn't matter whether you condition on that or its inverse.

The primal parameter is $\theta$ so we have
$$\mathcal{L}^*(\theta|\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\theta)$$
We define
$$\eta = \tau(\theta) \implies \theta = \tau^{-1}(\eta).$$
Insert this into the right-hand side
$$\theta = \tau^{-1}(\eta) \rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\tau^{-1}(\eta)).$$
Moreover, the left-hand-side must include the mathematical objects of the right hand side, hence $\mathcal{L}^*(\eta|\mathbf{x})$, since the new object is $\eta$.
